# How to convert a generic Object List to DataTable by specifying Property Name? - C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, datatable, system.reflection

I have created one function for converting List to Datatble. But I need to customize this function so that method will have additional parameter of List properties(eg:Name,Age) that are only to be considered while converting to  datatble. Also I want to maintain the order of columns same as what it is their in Property list.  Example - I am passing List (Customer having different properties Name,Age,DOB,Place) and list of Properties that to be converted ie List(Name,Age).Also I want to rename Datatable Column Header of Name as "Person Name " and Age as "Person Age".Can anyone help how can I achieve this.Also you can propose better logic to achieve the requirement.

```
      public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
                    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names  
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {

                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change your merthod to take a `Dictionary<string,string>` which acts as a mapping from the properties you're interested in to their mapped name. Then use this to filter the properties from the object and build the data table

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items, Dictionary<string,string> properties)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                               .Where(p => properties.ContainsKey(p.Name)).ToArray();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Setting column names as Property names  
        dataTable.Columns.Add(properties[prop.Name]);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {

            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
var props = new Dictionary<string,string>
{ 
    ["Name"] = "Person Name",
    ["Age"] = "Person Age"
};
var dt = ToDataTable(people, props);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XkJvV

Comment: I tried you code.But there is one issue.While converting to datatable,it should only need to consider columns specified in dictionary .It will throw error if i add an extra property in Person Object var people = new List<Person> { new Person{Name="Jamie", Age=10 , Location= "London"}, new Person{Name="Fred", Age=30, Location ="US" } }..I am getting error like this "Compilation error (line 11, col 69): 'Program.Person' does not contain a definition for 'Location'"

Comment: @vmb you forgot to add that new property to the `Person` class! It works fine when you do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsBIH7

Comment: @Jamiec..Its work like a charm. I have made few more customization based on my requirement. Thank you so much for your effort. People like you make this community more beautiful.

Comment: @vmb very happy I could help, and thanks for the kind words

Answer (score 1):

The [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) package already has a [ToDataTable](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ToDataTable.cs) method that works on any `IEnumerable<T>`. You can use LINQ's `Select` to shape the data in any way you want and then convert it to a DataTable with `ToDataTable` :

```
var table= customers.Select (customer => new {
               customer.Name,
               customer.DOB,
               Age=(DateTime.Today-customer.DOB).Days/365
           })
           .ToDataTable();
```

`ToDataTable` has an overload that allows you specify the properties to use through expressions:

```
var table=customers.ToDataTable(new[]{ c=>c.Name, c=>c.DOB });
```

And another that allows you to fill an already created and configured table. From one of [the unit tests](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/ee238241083a9b31dc03c39781b29f4189b4fe73/MoreLinq.Test/ToDataTableTest.cs#L160):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var columns = dt.Columns;
columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

var vars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
                      .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                      .ToArray();

vars.Select(e => new { Name = e.Key.ToString(), 
                       Value = e.Value.ToString() })
    .ToDataTable(dt, e => e.Name, e => e.Value);
```

**Columns with spaces**

You can change [DataColumn.ColumnName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.columnname?view=net-5.0) afterwards but perhaps a *better* solution would be to set the [Caption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.caption?view=net-5.0) property. The default value of `Caption` is the `ColumnName`. A name with spaces is almost certainly meant for display purposes.

It's better to leave `ColumnName` unmodified so you can identify columns by name, and change the display caption to whatever you need.

For example:

```
var personColumns=new[]{"Name","Age"};

foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    column.Caption = $"Person {column.ColumnName}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the new ida for achieving it